# Why Druid Sum Aggregator is getting Zero Always

Tags: hadoop, ambari, druid

We are trying to aggregate(sum) for one of the columns which is a string datatype. I was using Below Query. I Have Two Druid Servers are there which is having the same data. One is with Imply and the other is From Ambari installation. In Imply It was working And We got output as expected But From Ambari Druid I am getting Zero as output for the below queries. Below is my input Kafka spec for both(My Ambari druid server and Imply as well)

```
{"type": "kafka",
  "dataSchema": {"dataSource": "DRUID_RAIN","parser": {"type": "string",  "parseSpec": {    "format": "json",    "timestampSpec": {      "column": "DATE_TIME","format": "auto"},"flattenSpec": {"fields": [{ "type": "path","name": "deviceType","expr": "$.ENVIRONMENT.deviceType"},{ "type": "path","name": "NS","expr":"$.ENVIRONMENT.NS"},
{"type": "path","name": "latitude","expr": "$.ENVIRONMENT.latitude"},{ "type": "path","name": "TIME","expr": "$.ENVIRONMENT.TIME"},{ "type": "path","name": "tenantCode","expr": "$.ENVIRONMENT.tenantCode"},{ "type": "path","name": "deviceName","expr": "$.ENVIRONMENT.deviceName"},{ "type": "path","name": "MAC","expr": "$.ENVIRONMENT.MAC"},{ "type": "path","name": "DATE","expr": "$.ENVIRONMENT.DATE"},{ "type": "path","name": "RAIN","expr": "$.ENVIRONMENT.RAIN"},
{ "type": "path","name": "MESSAGE_ID","expr": "$.ENVIRONMENT.MESSAGE_ID"},{ "type": "path","name": "tenantId","expr": "$.ENVIRONMENT.tenantId"},{ "type": "path","name": "zoneId","expr": "$.ENVIRONMENT.zoneId"},{ "type": "path","name": "DATE_TIME","expr": "$.ENVIRONMENT.DATE_TIME"},{ "type": "path","name": "zoneName","expr": "$.ENVIRONMENT.zoneName" }, { "type": "path","name": "longitude","expr": "$.ENVIRONMENT.longitude"},{ "type": "path","name": "STATUS","expr": "$.ENVIRONMENT.STATUS"}]},"dimensionsSpec": {"dimensions":["deviceType","NS","latitude","TIME","tenantCode","deviceName","MAC","DATE","RAIN","MESSAGE_ID","tenantId","zoneId","DATE_TIME","zoneName","longitude","STATUS"]}}},"metricsSpec": [ ],"granularitySpec": {  "type": "uniform",  "segmentGranularity": "DAY",  "queryGranularity": {"type": "none"},"rollup": true,  "intervals": null},"transformSpec": {  "filter": null,  "transforms": []}},"tuningConfig": {"type": "kafka","maxRowsInMemory": 1000000,"maxBytesInMemory": 0,"maxRowsPerSegment": 5000000,"maxTotalRows": null,"intermediatePersistPeriod": "PT10M","maxPendingPersists": 0,"indexSpec": {  "bitmap": {    "type": "concise"},  "dimensionCompression": "lz4",  "metricCompression": "lz4","longEncoding": "longs"},"buildV9Directly": true,"reportParseExceptions": false,"handoffConditionTimeout": 0,"resetOffsetAutomatically": false,"segmentWriteOutMediumFactory": null,"workerThreads": null,"chatThreads": null,"chatRetries": 8,"httpTimeout": "PT10S","shutdownTimeout": "PT80S","offsetFetchPeriod": "PT30S","intermediateHandoffPeriod": "P2147483647D","logParseExceptions": false,"maxParseExceptions": 2147483647,"maxSavedParseExceptions": 0,"skipSequenceNumberAvailabilityCheck": false},
  "ioConfig": {"topic": "rain_out","replicas": 2,"taskCount": 1,"taskDuration": "PT5S","consumerProperties": {  "bootstrap.servers": "XXXX:6667,XXXX:6667,XXXX:6667"},"pollTimeout": 100,"startDelay": "PT10S","period": "PT30S","useEarliestOffset": true,"completionTimeout": "PT20S","lateMessageRejectionPeriod": null,"earlyMessageRejectionPeriod": null,"stream": "env_out","useEarliestSequenceNumber": true,"type": "kafka"},
  "context": null,
  "suspended": false}
```

And Below is my Query What I Have Written

```
{
  "queryType": "groupBy",
  "dataSource": "DRUID_RAIN",
  "granularity": "hour",
  "dimensions": [
    "zoneName",
    "deviceName"
  ],
 
  "limitSpec": {
    "type": "default",
    "limit": 5000,
    "columns": [
      "zoneName",
      "deviceName"
    ]
  },
  "aggregations": [
    {
      "type": "doubleSum",
      "name": "RAIN",
      "fieldName": "RAIN"
    }
  ],
  "intervals": [
    "2020-10-27T18:30:00.000/2020-10-28T18:30:00.000"
  ],
  "context": {
    "skipEmptyBuckets": "true"
  }
}
```

The output Always I am getting '0' for RAIN Column. I am not getting Expected Sum using from Postman or command line of druid DB.  But using imply I am getting exact output for the same query.